# Why Microsoft VS Code throws an error? How to make sure that many windows do not open, but everything is done in one window?

Tags: python, selenium, window, screenshot

Good day.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
 
    
def automation_func(url, i):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get("https://site.ru")
    btn_elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")
    btn_elem1.click()
    btn_elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/label/input")
    btn_elem2.click()
    btn_elem2.send_keys("login")
    btn_elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[2]/label/input")
    btn_elem3.click()
    btn_elem3.send_keys("pass")
    btn_elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a")
    btn_elem4.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get(url)
    btn_elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/img[1]")
    btn_elem5.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if "Даво" in driver.page_source:
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("{i}.png")
 
 
def main():
    for i in range(4, 12000):
        automation_func(f"https://site.ru/lookup/{i}", i)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example above - everything works, but every time a new window opens. Everything is clear, because it is written in the function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
 
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get("https://site.ru")
    btn_elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")
    btn_elem1.click()
    btn_elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/label/input")
    btn_elem2.click()
    btn_elem2.send_keys("login")
    btn_elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[2]/label/input")
    btn_elem3.click()
    btn_elem3.send_keys("pass")
    btn_elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a")
    btn_elem4.click()
 
def automation_func(url, i):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    btn_elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/img[1]")
    btn_elem5.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if "Даво" in driver.page_source:
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("{i}.png")
 
 
def main():
    for i in range(4, 12000):
        automation_func(f"https://site.ru/lookup/{i}", i)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here I wanted to display it separately. So that the function contains only what is needed. To prevent many windows from opening. Since you have to go over more than 10 thousand pages. Gives an error message.

There is always one mistake. driver and main are underlined. If you put different indents, then something gets better there, then another error. In general, it already seems to have gone through all the options.

Undefined variable 'driver'
Undefined variable 'driver'
Undefined variable 'driver'
Undefined variable 'driver'
function already defined line 9
Unused variable 'screenshot'

There is also a suspicion that the screenshot does not work. Or I didn't find the path where the images are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Few things for you to consider:

1. You have two main() functions.

When you execute the script and try to call **main()**, which one do you expect to be called?

I suggest you rename the first one after it's purpose (e.g. CreateDriver or SetUpWedriver or such)

2. Your `automation_func()` has no context of `driver`. That's why you'll be getting so many undefined errors around it.

In your first main (the one to rename) you have

```
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    ...
```

That line initialises the variable called "driver". That variable only exists in the context of that function. Once the function finishes all the variables are destroyed to release the memory.

Compare that to your first block of code where all the actions are done in a single block of code - therefore they all know what `driver` is.

With that variable-context in mind consider that you have:

```
def automation_func(url, i):
    driver.get(url)
```

How will this function know what driver is? It has not been initiated.

The answer to this is to declare the variable outside the function - this makes it accessible everywhere.

Top of your script will look like this:

```py
#...other imports
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#note - renamed! - used to be main()
def CreateDriver():    
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
#rest of code below
```

---

Finally - The site you provide in the code doesn't work for me. That means i can't fully test it, but putting the above pieces together, I think you might want this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

#Note - moved outside the functions so it's accessible to all
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#note - renamed! - this is not responsible for setting up the driver
def CreateDriver():    
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get("https://site.ru")
    btn_elem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]")
    btn_elem1.click()
    btn_elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[1]/label/input")
    btn_elem2.click()
    btn_elem2.send_keys("login")
    btn_elem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/p[2]/label/input")
    btn_elem3.click()
    btn_elem3.send_keys("pass")
    btn_elem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a")
    btn_elem4.click()
 
def automation_func(url, i):
    CreateDriver  # this gets the driver into the state we want
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    btn_elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/fieldset/div[2]/img[1]")
    btn_elem5.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if "Даво" in driver.page_source:
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("{i}.png")
 
 
def main():
    for i in range(4, 12000):
        automation_func(f"https://site.ru/lookup/{i}", i)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Last note - your additional question:  Your screenshot does work.

You're not specifying a path, so when your code reaches that point it creates the screenshot in the same directory as the python file that is being executed.

If you're not seeing the screenshot, it's most likely because that line of code hasn't run yet or your IF function doesn't meet the right condition.